# Concatenate string variables into a new variable in new table

Tags: sql, select, casting, isnull, select-into

I am trying to concatenate 5 string variables into a new string in a new table.

```
SELECT [id],IsNull(Cast(x01 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x02 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x03 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x04 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x05 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable AS [id],[new_string];
```

I don't understand the error message produced, because I am creating a new table - how can the column name be missing? I am expecting two variables in the new table: id, new_string

**An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name**

Comment: It tells you the error - you don't have a name for the column.  Add one:  SELECT [id], ... [name] INTO newtable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [id],IsNull(Cast(x01 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x02 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x03 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x04 as nvarchar(4000)),'')
+ IsNull(Cast(x05 as nvarchar(4000)),'') as new_string
                                ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
```

Give the column a name, so it can be used to create the new table.